# Что/чего я не знаю?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Что я о тебе не знаю?

или

> Чего я о тебе не знаю?

Сначала я решил, что правильно "что", потом "чего", а сейчас окончательно запутался. Как правильно? А если оба варианта правильные, какие есть между ними смысловые различия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предпочла *Чего я о тебе не знаю?*

> При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно преобладает
>   употребление родительного падежа дополнения, в других – употребление
>   винительного падежа, в третьих – наблюдается факультативное их
>   использование.
>
> 1. Родительный падеж, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение подчеркнутого отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях: ...
>      3) при глаголах восприятия, мысли, желания, ожидания (видеть, слышать,  понимать, думать, **знать,** хотеть, желать, ожидатьи т.п.),
> 2. Винительный падеж, ослабляющий значение отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:
>
>    при указании на конкретный объект («именно этот предмет, а не  вообще какой-то»);
>
>    нередко при инверсии дополнения (постановке его впереди глагола-сказуемого), например:
>      Журнал я этот не люблю (Тургенев);
>
>    4)      в вопросительных и восклицательных предложениях,
>      общий смысл которых **не имеет характера отрицания**;
>
>    5)    в побудительных предложениях (со сказуемым в форме  повелительного наклонения), в связи с их разговорным характером;
>
>    6)    при форме совершенного вида глагола-сказуемого, указывающей на результативность действия, например: ...Не передам бронепоезд никому  другому (Вс. Иванов);
>
>    7)      при  двойном отрицании;
>
>    8)      при совпадении различных, но
>      одинаково звучащих падежных форм для устранения неясности: не читал  сегодня газету (форма газеты могла бы обозначать множественное число).
>
>    9)    при наличии слов (частиц) с ограничительным значением: чуть не пропустил лекцию, едва не уронил стакан ; 
>      10)  при наличии в предложении  слова, по смыслу относящегося одновременно к прямому дополнению и к
>      сказуемому;
>
>    11)  при распространении дополнения несколькими
>      определениями;
>
>    12)  обычно в конструкции «не +  вспомогательный глагол + инфинитив переходного глагола + дополнение»
>      (т.е. при отнесении дополнения не непосредственно к глаголу с  отрицанием, а к инфинитиву, зависящему от глагола с отрицанием, что
>      ослабляет влияние отрицания): не мог представить рукопись, не надеялся  выполнить задание.
>
>    13)  в устойчивых сочетаниях, пословицах,
>      поговорках, обычно при выражении дополнения конкретным
>      существительным, например: не вставлять палки в колеса, не скалить  зубы.
> 3. Факультативное употребление родительного и винительного падежа при переходном глаголе с отрицанием связано со стилистическим различием: конструкции с родительным падежом характерны для книжной речи, конструкции с винительным падежом – для речи разговорной. Ср.: Я не умаляю чьих-либо заслуг... (Горький). – Так и умрешь, не выговорив это слово (он же).
> 4. При глаголах с приставкой недо-, не имеющей значения отрицания, а указывающей на выполнение действия ниже нормы, дополнение обычно ставится в форме винительного падежа, например: недогрузить тонну угля, недодать почту, недолить стакан, недооценить силу противника, недопечь пирог, недовыполнить план; родительный падеж в этих случаях употребляется при количественно-разделительном значении объекта, например: недодать деталей, недовесить масла, недодать кирпича, недолить воды, недослать денег.
> 5. Постановка прямого дополнения в форме винительного падежа обязательна в тех случаях, когда отрицание «не» стоит не при переходном глаголе, а при другом слове в предложении, например: не вполне понял задание, не очень люблю живопись, не часто читаю художественную литературу.
>      [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04(параграф](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04(%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84) 201)

Вот если бы имелось в виду **что-то конкретное,** предпочтителен был бы винительный падеж:

- *А вот это ты  не знаешь...*
- *Что я о тебе не знаю?*

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Я так понимаю, здесь подходит пункт 3., то есть падеж зависит от того, является ли речь книжной или разговорной.